# Ford Sync and Reminders problem iPhone 4s

Tags: data-synchronization, iphone, bluetooth, car-integration

My 2010 Ford Edge has Sync but not the nav system. The phone is paired. With radio off, a phone call works fine through the car's system, but reminders only vibrate the phone and there is no sound. If the radio is on, the reminders can be heard. The dealer upgraded the Sync so it is current. He said something about privacy mode, but I can't find that on my phone.

I deleted all devices from the car's bluetooth memory and re-paired the phone. No help.

How to make reminders audible while driving with radio off?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think this is possible. I have a 2010 Fusion with Sync and no nav. The iPhone's ringtone is the only thing that will preempt the current audio setting if it is not Bluetooth Audio. Any other sounds (text message, reminder, turn-by-turn directions using Waze or MapQuest) are only audible if Bluetooth Audio is selected, a phone call is already in progress, or Siri is active. In other words, the phone's audio must already be playing to hear any alert other than a ringing phone. (caveat: I do not use Sync's USB or line-in connections for my iPhone.)

Privacy mode is when you manually change your call audio from Sync back to the iPhone using the audio sources button; the radio will display "Privacy Mode" and mute whatever is playing as long as you're on the phone.